# Why are YouTube downloads being deleted from my tablet but not my phone?

Tags: youtube, samsung-galaxy-tab, oppo-coloros

I have an Oppo AX5 phone and a Samsung Galaxy Tab A tablet. If I download the same youtube video to both devices, within 48 hours or so something deletes it from the tablet but not the phone. It must be a setting or an app on the tablet, but I have exhausted every lead I can think of without finding the culprit. Probably something obvious ...doh! Any clues will be gratefully accepted. Bandwidth is slow and expensive in my part of the world,  so I need to be able to download a resource once and not have it disappear!

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: May be the automatic Samsung storage optimizer? https://www.samsung.com/in/support/mobile-devices/samsung-phone-optimise-clean-storage-and-memory/

Comment: There can be various reasons. For starters do you have the same rom version and apps installed on both and are the settings the same?

Comment: @Robert That was my first thought too. Automatic optimisation has been turned off so it does not happen on a schedule, but I wonder now if it happens at boot up whether I want it to or not?

Comment: @CFCBazarcom as the devices are from different manufacturers, I doubt they share a rom. Those apps common to both devices share the same settings.

Comment: Try this: https://www.howtogeek.com/442976/how-to-automatically-delete-your-youtube-history/

Comment: @CFCBazarcom how does that affect the problem of videos being deleted from my tablet? They are not being deleted from my phone so it cannot be a YouTube issue surely?

Comment: If the option to delete your activity is selected, that can delete the videos that were downloaded previously from youtube.